# SHA1 and openssl sha1 difference

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I used sha1, created by keytool available in jdk bin directory to sign our apk. Now I am integrating facebook in our app first time. here I need to put openssl sha1 in dashbord in facebook developer site. I realy confuse about both these sha1 (needed while signing apk) and openssl sha1(needed in dashboard of facebook developer site). Is both same ? 
I have seen hash value is different created by both way.